# Java, parent-child recursion

Tags: java

I've been having trouble with this snippet of code:

```
public static void fillMenu(MenuItem menuItem, Set<MenuItem> menuItems) {
    if (menuItem.getParentID() == 0) {
        menuItems.add(menuItem);
    } else {
        for (Iterator<MenuItem> iterator = menuItems.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            MenuItem currentItem = iterator.next();
            if (currentItem.getID() == menuItem.getParentID()) {
                menuItem.setParent(currentItem);
                currentItem.addChild(menuItem);
                continue;
            }

            fillMenu(menuItem, currentItem.getChildren());
        }
    }
}
```

This is not adding my child elements. Can someone please help? Thanks.

Comment: Does `currentItem.getChildren()`  include `currentItem` itself? If not, then your code never adds the children to their parent.

Comment: I want to add children to parent elements. I am selecting nodes from db ordered byt id_parent.

Comment: Do you really want to `break;` or should it be `continue;` ?

Comment: changed to continue.

Comment: currentItem.addChild(menuItem); this code adds the child properly, but the change is not seen after the loop goes on in menuItems that I iterate.

Comment: @user2421904 I wasn't being rhetorical in my question nor wanting you to update your question.  `break` and `continue` do different things.  What does changing it to continue do?  Unless it reproduces the same error I would leave your question as it was when you first asked it.

Comment: error is the same after I changed it to continue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with your if statement `if (currentItem.getID() == menuItem.getParentID())`  This doesn't make sense since `menuItem.getParentID()` should be the head of the list and `currentItem.getID()` is not.